# VBA Merge Similar Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to merge similar cells by columns, as of now I am using this macro

```
Sub MergeSimilarCells()

    Set myRange = Range("A1:Z300")

CheckAgain:
    For Each cell In myRange
        If cell.Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value And Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, 1)).Merge
            cell.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            GoTo CheckAgain
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

My problem is with hundreds of rows and 40-50 columns, it takes forever. 
I am pretty sure a For Loop could help me there but I am not skilled enough to figure it out

I know the following code is wrong but I am lost

```
Sub SimilarCells()
  Set myRange = Range("A1:G4")
    Dim count As Integer

CheckAgain:
    count = 1

    For Each cell In myRange
        If cell.Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value And Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            count = count + 1

        ElseIf cell.Value <> cell.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
            Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, -count)).Merge
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

[image: Excel example data]

Here is what I would like to accomplish

[image: Final Result]

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I want to merge cells left and right,  I am not sure how conditional formatting would help.  I added a picture for what I would like to accomplish

Comment: Actually, quite nice input in the question, thinking of lots of corner cases. Good job, consider attending QA courses as well, this is the way to go (info from your profile) (:

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub MergeMe()    

    Dim wks As Worksheet: Set wks = Worksheets(1)
    Dim myRange As Range: Set myRange = wks.Range("B2:H5")
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim myCell2 As Range

    Dim firstColumn As Long: firstColumn = myRange.Columns(1).column + 1
    Dim lastColumn As Long: lastColumn = firstColumn + myRange.Columns.Count - 1
    Dim firstRow As Long: firstRow = myRange.Rows(1).row
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = firstRow + myRange.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim column As Long
    Dim row As Long

    OnStart

    For column = lastColumn To firstColumn Step -1
        For row = lastRow To firstRow Step -1
            Set myCell = wks.Cells(row, column)
            Set myCell2 = myCell.Offset(0, -1)
            If myCell.Value = myCell2.Value Then
                With wks.Range(myCell, myCell2)
                    .Merge
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                End With
            End If
        Next row
    Next column

    OnEnd

End Sub
```

There are quite a few tricks in this code:

- we need to get the first and last column and row;
- then we should be looping from the last cell (bottom right) to the first one (top left);
- we should not enter the first column, because we are using `.Offset(0,-1)` and we compare every cell with its leftmost one;
- **the reason for the whole operation**, is that by default, the value of a merged cells is kept in its left top cell. The other cells of a merged cell are without a value.
- This is why we always compare the merged cells with their "left" neighbour;

These are the `OnEnd` and `OnStart`, facilitating the operation.

```
Public Sub OnEnd()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False
    Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub

Public Sub OnStart()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Only one merge per group

EDITED to fix - thanks Vityata for the heads-up

```
Sub MergeEm()

    Dim rw As Range, i As Long, s As Long, v

    Range("C21:J33").Copy Range("C5:J17")  'for testing purposes: replace previous run

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each rw In Range("C5:J17").Rows 'or wherever
        i = 1
        s = 1
        Do While i < (rw.Cells.Count)
            v = rw.Cells(i).Value
            'check for a run of same values
            Do While Len(v) > 0 And v = rw.Cells(i + s).Value
                s = s + 1
                If i + s > rw.Cells.Count Then Exit Do
            Loop
            'if s>1 then had a run: merge those ells
            If s > 1 Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                rw.Cells(i).Resize(1, s).Merge
                rw.Cells(i).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                i = i + s 'skip over the merged range
                s = 1     'reset s
            Else
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Loop
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, it is a really interesting solution, **but** it does not work. Have you tried it with the input data from the OP? I have just tried it, and in the lower right corner, it did not merge the word "Class". Tried it on range "B2:H5". So, time to rewrite... :D

Comment: And it also does not merge the word "Class" on the third row completely... The input from the OOP is quite nice, give it a try.

Comment: @Vityata - thanks, fixed.  I should test using the OP's data...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure what bloats your processing time is the `goto` causing you to loop through everything yet again every time after every merge

Edit to take column `A` into account and prevent first column cells to merge with cells outside of `myRange`:

```
Sub MergeSimilarCells()

Dim i As Long
Dim myCol As String


Set myRange = Range("K1:L30")

myCol = Left(myRange.Address(True, False), InStr(myRange.Offset(0, 1).Address(True, False), "$") - 1)

If Not Intersect(myRange, Range(myCol & ":" & myCol)).Address = myRange.Address Then
    Set myRange = Range(Replace(myRange.Address, Left(myRange.Address(True, False), _
        InStr(myRange.Address(True, False), "$")), Left(myRange.Offset(0, 1).Address(True, False), _
        InStr(myRange.Offset(0, 1).Address(True, False), "$"))))
    For i = myRange.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        If myRange.Item(i).Value = myRange.Item(i).Offset(0, -1).Value And Not IsEmpty(myRange.Item(i)) Then
            Range(myRange.Item(i), myRange.Item(i).Offset(0, -1)).Merge
            myRange.Item(i).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            myRange.Item(i).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End If
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

To clarify why `myRange` has to start in column `B`: `Offset(0, -1)` of any cell in column `A` will cause an error since there is no column to the left of `A`.

Comment: Quite sophisticated, **but** I know you know why `myRange` starts from the second column in your example. ;)

Comment: @Vityata - indeed I do :) I've added a brief paragraph explaining why to my answer

Comment: As I mentioned, I knew you know it :) More interesting question, though - can you make it work with column "A" and the same logic?

Comment: @Vityata - I understood it as a hint to add an explanation (then saw your more complete one afterwards...). Not sure I understand what you mean by "can you make it work with column "A" and the same logic". Cells in column `A` will get merged if they match what's in column `B`

Comment: Imagine that the initial range that is passed is `"A1:H30"` and it should work with this one. I was thinking of using `mod` operator and the length of the row or something, thus skipping every first column.